# python urllib2 HTTPSHandler error

Tags: python, opensuse, openssl

I just installed openSuse 12.3 server onto my server and I have been loading everything onto it from the old server(CentOS 6.2) and I use python as my programming language and I tried to use pip to install things but pip is throwing a global error(it throws it no matter what) that urllib2 HTTPSHandler is not there or can not be imported... opensuse comes with openssl so where am I going wrong here? Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that opensuse installed the very minimum of python with the text server installation which means that you have to install python from yast or zypper or wherever you wish to, to get ssl and HTTPS working... (most annoying)

Solution:

`sudo zypper install python`

and choose solution 1 (deinstallation of patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts)